# Site title not aligned to the right in sharepoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, communication-site, mui

I have the site in english as the main language, added Arabic as the secondary language. When I view the site in arabic, the logo gets aligned to the right but the site title and the menu does not. Please check.

[image]

Kindly advise how to fix the layout.

Edit:
This issue happens when I add application customizer to add a footer to the site. This messes up with the site title, menu and the calendar, links web parts and changes the layout from left to right.

Below is my code: SCSS file:

```
    @import '~@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core/dist/sass/SPFabricCore.scss';

:global {

/*  div[class^="feedback_"]{

    display: none !important;

} */

  body, /* entire body*/
  .ms-Nav, /*left navigation pane background*/
  #spPageChromeAppDiv /* whole page again*/
  {
      background-color: #f2f3f4  !important;
  }
  .o365cs-base.o365cs-topnavBGColor-2, /* top bar*/
  .o365cs-base .o365cs-nav-rightMenus /* top bar menu right*/
  {
      background-color: #3B3890 !important;
  }

  
  #O365_NavHeader{

    background-color: #3B3890 !important;
    
    }
    
    #O365_MainLink_NavMenu{
    
    background-color: #3B3890 !important;
    
    }

 a{
    
  font-size: x-small;
 }
 a:hover {
    color: silver;
  }

}

.app {

  .navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #3B3890;
  }
  
  .navbar a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  
  
  

  .top {
      height:80px;
      text-align:center;
      line-height:2.5;
      font-weight:bold;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: left;
      background-color: #3B3890;
      color: $ms-color-white;
      border-bottom: 3px solid silver;
      border-top: 3px solid silver;
  }


  .top1 {
   
    text-align:center;
    line-height:2.5;
    font-weight:bold;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: left;
    height:80px;
    color: $ms-color-white;
    width: 70%;
    padding-left:5px;
    }
    .top2 {
      height:80px;
      text-align:center;
      line-height:2.5;
      font-weight:bold;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: right;
      color: $ms-color-white;
      width: 30%;
      margin-right: 20px;
      }

      .top3 {
        
        text-align:center;
        line-height:2.5;
        font-weight:bold;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        
        color: $ms-color-white;
        width: 10%;
        }
        .top4 {
          
          text-align:center;
          line-height:2.5;
          font-weight:bold;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          
          color: $ms-color-white;
          width: 10%;
          }

          .top6 {
          
            text-align:center;
            line-height:2.5;
            font-weight:bold;
           // display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            
            color: $ms-color-white;
            width: 10%;
            }
          .top5 {
            
            text-align:center;
            line-height:2.5;
            font-weight:bold;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            
            color: $ms-color-white;
            width: 10%;
            }

           
  .bottom {
      height:40px;
      text-align:left;
      line-height:2.5;
       display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: left;
      //background-color: $ms-color-themePrimary;
      background-color: #3B3890;
      color: $ms-color-white;
      border-top: 3px solid silver;
      padding-left: 5px;
      font-size: smaller;
  }


  .bottom1 {
    height:40px;
    text-align:left;
    line-height:2.5;
     display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: left;
    //background-color: $ms-color-themePrimary;
    background-color: #3B3890;
    color: $ms-color-white;
    border-top: 3px solid silver;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-size: smaller;
    width: 30%;
}

.bottom2 {
  width: 70%;
  height:40px;
  text-align:left;
  line-height:2.5;
   display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: right;
  //background-color: $ms-color-themePrimary;
  background-color: #3B3890;
  color: $ms-color-white;
  border-top: 3px solid silver;
  padding-left: 5px;
  font-size: smaller;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.navbarbottom {
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbarbottom a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px 7px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: x-small; 
  
}

.navbarbottom a:hover {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}

.navbarbottom a.active {
  background-color: silver;
  color: white;
}
 
}
```

And my application customizer code:

```
import { override } from '@microsoft/decorators';
import { Log } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  BaseApplicationCustomizer
} from '@microsoft/sp-application-base';
import { Dialog } from '@microsoft/sp-dialog';
import styles from './AppCustomizer.module.scss';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import { confirm } from "react-confirm-box";

import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
    PlaceholderContent,
  PlaceholderName
} from '@microsoft/sp-application-base';

import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap";
require('../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
require('../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');


import * as strings from 'SbcHeaderFooterApplicationCustomizerStrings';

const LOG_SOURCE: string = 'SbcHeaderFooterApplicationCustomizer';



/**
 * If your command set uses the ClientSideComponentProperties JSON input,
 * it will be deserialized into the BaseExtension.properties object.
 * You can define an interface to describe it.
 */
export interface ISbcHeaderFooterApplicationCustomizerProperties {
  // This is an example; replace with your own property
  Top: string;
  Bottom: string;
}



/** A Custom Action which can be run during execution of a Client Side Application */
export default class SbcHeaderFooterApplicationCustomizer
  extends BaseApplicationCustomizer<ISbcHeaderFooterApplicationCustomizerProperties> {
  
    
    // These have been added
  private _topPlaceholder: PlaceholderContent | undefined;
  private _bottomPlaceholder: PlaceholderContent | undefined;

  @override
  public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, `Initialized ${strings.Title}`);
  
    // Wait for the placeholders to be created (or handle them being changed) and then
    // render.
    this.context.placeholderProvider.changedEvent.add(this, this._renderPlaceHolders);
  
    return Promise.resolve();
  }


  private _renderPlaceHolders(): void {
    console.log("HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer._renderPlaceHolders()");
    console.log(
      "Available placeholders: ",
      this.context.placeholderProvider.placeholderNames
        .map(name => PlaceholderName[name])
        .join(", ")
    );

    var absolutePath:string = this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl;

    // $('.ms-compositeHeader').css('display','none');    
  
    // Handling the top placeholder
//     if (!this._topPlaceholder) {
//       this._topPlaceholder = this.context.placeholderProvider.tryCreateContent(
//         PlaceholderName.Top,
//         { onDispose: this._onDispose }
//       );
  
//       // The extension should not assume that the expected placeholder is available.
//       if (!this._topPlaceholder) {
//         console.error("The expected placeholder (Top) was not found.");
//         return;
//       }
  
//       if (this.properties) {
//         let topString: string = this.properties.Top;
//         if (!topString) {
//           topString = "(Top property was not defined.)";
//         }
  
//  /*        if (this._topPlaceholder.domElement) {
//           this._topPlaceholder.domElement.innerHTML = `



//           <div class="${styles.app}">
//             <div class="${styles.top}">



//               <div class="${styles.top1}" >  
//                 <div  class="${styles.navbar}" >
            
//                         <div  class="${styles.dropdown}"  >
//                           <a  class="${styles.dropbtn}" href="${absolutePath}"/SitePages/Home.aspx">${strings.Home}
//                           </a>
//                         </div> 

            
//                         <div  class="${styles.dropdown}"  >
//                           <button  class="${styles.dropbtn}">${strings.About_Us} 
//                           </button>
//                           <div  class="${styles.dropdowncontent}">
//                             <a href="https://business.sa/AboutSBC/About.html">${strings.SBC_Overview}</a>
//                             <a href="https://business.sa/AboutSBC/About.html">${strings.Objectives}</a>
//                             <a href="https://business.sa/AboutSBC/Board.html">${strings.Board_Members}</a>
//                           </div>
//                         </div> 

//                   <div class="${styles.dropdown}">
//                     <button class="${styles.dropbtn}">${strings.Departments}</button>
//                     <div  class="${styles.dropdowncontent}">
//                       <a href=""  style="background-color:#E6EFFA">${strings.Shared_Services}</a>
//                       <a href="">${strings.Finance}</a>
//                       <a href="">${strings.Contracts_Procurement}</a>
//                       <a href="">${strings.HR}</a>
//                       <a href="">${strings.IT}</a>
//                       <a href="">${strings.Admin_Services}</a>
//                       <a href="">${strings.Project_Management}</a>
                                      
//                       <a href=""  style="background-color:#E6EFFA">${strings.Communication_Marketing}</a>
//                       <a href="">${strings.Marketing_Communication}</a>
//                       <a href="">${strings.Public_Relations}</a>
//                       <a href="">${strings.Events_and_Confrences}</a>

                              
//                       <a href=""  style="background-color:#E6EFFA">${strings.Business_Intelligence}</a>
//                       <a href="">${strings.Data_Analysis}</a>
//                       <a href="">${strings.Economic_Reports}</a>
//                       <a href="">${strings.Lists_URP}</a>

                              
//                       <a href=""  style="background-color:#E6EFFA">${strings.Investor_Services}</a>
//                       <a href="">${strings.Spatial_Centers}</a>
//                       <a href="">${strings.Unified_Digital_Platform}</a>
//                       <a href="">${strings.Investors_Services}</a>

//                       <a href=""  style="background-color:#E6EFFA">${strings.Policies_Regulations}</a>
//                       <a href="">${strings.Dev_Policies_Regulations}</a>
              
//                       <a href=""  style="background-color:#E6EFFA">${strings.Partnerships_Capacity_Dev}</a>
//                       <a href="">${strings.Capacity_Operations_Dev}</a>
//                       <a href="">${strings.Quality}</a>
//                       <a href="">${strings.Partnersips}</a>
//                     </div>
//                   </div>

//                       <div  class="${styles.dropdown}"  >
//                             <a  class="${styles.dropbtn}" href="${absolutePath}/SitePages/Home.aspx">${strings.Circulation} 
//                             </a>
//                       </div> 
//                       <div  class="${styles.dropdown}"  >
//                             <a  class="${styles.dropbtn}" href="${absolutePath}/SitePages/Home.aspx">${strings.News} 
//                             </a>
//                       </div>
//                  </div>
//               </div>     
              
              
                    
//               <div class="${styles.top2}">              
//               <a href='${absolutePath}/SitePages/Home.aspx'    > 
//               <img src='${absolutePath}/SiteImages/logos/XXX-LOGO_300_72.png' style="height:60px;width:300px" alt="Search"> 
//               </a>
//               </div>  


//             </div>
//           </div>`;
//         } */
//       }
//     }
  
    // Handling the bottom placeholder
    if (!this._bottomPlaceholder) {
      this._bottomPlaceholder = this.context.placeholderProvider.tryCreateContent(
        PlaceholderName.Bottom,
        { onDispose: this._onDispose }
      );
  
      // The extension should not assume that the expected placeholder is available.
      if (!this._bottomPlaceholder) {
        console.error("The expected placeholder (Bottom) was not found.");
        return;
      }

      //const elem: React.ReactElement<IReactFooterProps> = React.createElement(ReactFooter);

      //ReactDOM.render(elem, this._bottomPlaceholder.domElement); 
  
      if (this.properties) {
        let bottomString: string = this.properties.Bottom;
        if (!bottomString) {
          bottomString = "(Bottom property was not defined.)";
        }
  
        if (this._bottomPlaceholder.domElement) {
          this._bottomPlaceholder.domElement.innerHTML = `
          <div class="${styles.app}">
            <div class="${styles.bottom}">

            <div class="${styles.bottom2}">
            <div class="${styles.navbarbottom}">
            
            
           
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/XXX?utm_medium=copy_link">${strings.Instagram}</a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/XXX?s=20">${strings.Twitter}</a>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/XXX">${strings.Youtube}</a>
            <a href="https://sa.linkedin.com/company/XXX">${strings.Linkedin}</a>
          </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="${styles.bottom1}">
            ${strings.Copyright_first} ${new Date().getFullYear()} ${strings.Copyright_Second}
            </div>

           
            </div>
          </div>`;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private _onDispose(): void {
    console.log('[HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer._onDispose] Disposed custom top and bottom placeholders.');
  }
}
```

Kindly help fix this error.

Comment: Is this a bespoke/customised page layout or is it out-of-the-box?

Comment: Out of the box communication site

Comment: You'll probably need to raise this with Microsoft support.